# Seems like OptimizeExpression is getting worse over time

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I've been using the `OptimizeExpression` function again recently, and cleaning up the results by hand. Its results have been unbelievably sub-optimal in my recent usage, as opposed to the past. So much so that it doesn't even require manipulation of the results to see.

Have any of you run into this recently? Can you test this on older versions?

For context I'm in Mathematica Online, so I'm using version 12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 31, 2019). I don't use the desktop version.

```
f[u1@P]+c f[u2@P]/.f@u_->3/2/u(1/2/u-1/Tan[2u])//FullSimplify
{%,%/D[%,P]}/.{u1->(j1 Sqrt@#&),u2->(j2 Sqrt@#&)}//FullSimplify
Experimental`OptimizeExpression[%,OptimizationSymbol->a]
```

[image: suboptimal output]

Comment: I really wonder if this function is maintained at all ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Well, if they quit maintaining it, I'd like them to expose whatever function they're currently using for compiling functions for plotting, etc... Unless they're actually still using this function without maintaining it...

Comment: @Szabolcs It seems to me if the function is not maintained (= ignored?), then no change in behavior should be observed. -- BTW, the third underlined expression contains `Power[j1, -2]` and is not the same as `a18 = Power[j1, 2]`.  I have observed similar behavior to `OptimizeExpression` not using `Power[a18, -1]` in place of `Power[j1, -2]` in earlier versions. If you think about it, it is not more optimal; at least on the face of it, both require evaluating `Power`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 One of them requires either dividing or exponentiating one more time than the other (per substitution) after compilation, so I disagree. Besides, it is plain to see that it has missed plenty of other substitutions (for example in my answer below, but also in regular usage of the function). My guess is that it is bitrotting due to a lack of QA or automated regression testing on that function.

Comment: There is no dividing: there's multiplying by `Power[expr, -n]`.  It's been noted before that `Divide[a, b]` evaluates (on nonnumeric input) to `Times[a, Power[b, -1]]`, which is less efficient. You're saying, I take it, that in earlier versions, these expressions were optimized -- is that right?  Have you tried `OptimizationLevel -> 2`?  I'm unclear whether you're saying level `1` is not as optimal as possible or as optimal as it was in some previous version.

Comment: Don't you think I know the stuff about Power, Times, and Divide? I'm saying that this function was introduced to make compiled code execute faster. After it is compiled, the operations you're talking about actually are slower.  You've also ignored the other more serious back substitution misses I outlined in my answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I had originally attempted to address your question about optimization levels in the question, I somehow I deleted that before posting. The optimization level doesn't matter. It still keeps screwing things up (the effect of the option depends on the expression, but the option does not take care of the the types of problems I'm bringing up here)

Comment: The result in V5.2 is `{(3 a38)/(4 j1^2 j2^2 P), -((P a38)/(a19 + a20 - j1 j2 a25 (a35 + j2 (a27 + 2 j1 a25 (Csc[a26]^2 + c Csc[a29]^2)))))}` which is slightly different, but still has the powers of j1 and j2 in the denominator.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I just tried in v10.0 and it seems that the result is the same (except for different numbering of the Block variables)

Comment: @BrettChampion thanks. It looks like in your 5.2 version, the other substitutions I outlined in my answer would no longer apply. I wonder if that means the old function has had its output changed a bit to where now the other types of substitutions do matter and thus are effectively "missed"

Comment: "One of them requires either dividing or exponentiating one more time than the other" -- this is not true. `Power` is used 9 times in both, and there is no dividing as I explained.  Examine the output in both. -- "You've also ignored the other more serious back substitution misses I outlined in my answer."  This also is not true, and prompted my follow-up remarks about the optimization level. It's still unclear whether you're interested in historical changes to the function or why limiting the optimization level results in limited optimization. Level 2 does not have these problems.

Comment: All that aside, I get the feeling that my attempts at help are irritating you. That is not my wish and it's unpleasant to me. If that's the case I'll just stop trying.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It's because the messages are going to make support think everything is ok... But I don't agree that it is. For example, in C++ If I calculate and store the square of a number, it is in fact more efficient to, in a later calculation, just divide by the stored number [1 op] than to do any one of the following 3 things: divide twice by the original number [2 ops], re-calculate the square and divide by that [at least two ops], or calculate the negative 2 power of a number and then multiply by it [at least two ops].

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround while we wait for support to answer... It uses `a18=j1^2` and `a20=j2^2` as I underlined above, and also uses `a29=2*j2*a25` and `a36=a28+a35`.

```
f[u1@P]+c f[u2@P]/.f@u_->3/2/u(1/2/u-1/Tan[2u])//FullSimplify;
{%,%/D[%,P]}/.{u1->(j1 Sqrt@#&),u2->(j2 Sqrt@#&)}//FullSimplify;
Experimental`OptimizeExpression[%,OptimizationSymbol->a]
Out@3/.{Set->Rule,Experimental`OptimizedExpression|Block|
 CompoundExpression->List};
%[[1,2]];
Reverse@Fold[Flatten[{#//.Reverse@#2//.Reverse[1/#&/@#2],#2}]&,
 Reverse@%]
```

[image: OptimizeExpression simplified]

Comment: What is `Out@3`?  The line number depends on the session.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Look at the screen shot... or start a new kernel